# internal function call not working in ipython

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

the following occurring only while using ipython not the python terminal

```
def function1(name):
    return name

def function2(name):
    return "hello "+function1(name)
```

it generates the following error:

global name 'function1' is not defined

I'm using python 2.7 and calling IPython using python by typing the following command

```
from IPython import embed
embed()
```

this issue doesn't occurs while using jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an ongoing-bug that get's fixed and later ends up reappearing. Essentially, whatever you type into your shell gets added to `locals()` but the functions, when called, still check `globals()`.

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/62

A quick, hackey fix is to use:

```
globals().update(locals())
```

in the embedded session.

Suppose I make a file, `test.py`:

```
from IPython import embed
print "hello, ipython"

embed()
```

Now, I do:

```
(py27) Juans-MacBook-Pro:~ juan$ python ip.py
hello, ipython
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:05:08)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: def function1(name):
   ...:     return name
   ...:
   ...: def function2(name):
   ...:     return "hello "+function1(name)
   ...:

In [2]: function2('Juan')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/juan/ip.py in <module>()
----> 1 function2('Juan')

/Users/juan/ip.py in function2(name)
      3
      4 def function2(name):
----> 5     return "hello "+function1(name)

NameError: global name 'function1' is not defined
```

Weird. But true!

In [3]: globals()
Out[3]:
{'**builtins**': ,
 '**doc**': None,
 '**file**': 'ip.py',
 '**name**': '**main**',
 '**package**': None,
 'embed': }

And note:

```
In [4]: 'function1' in globals()
Out[4]: False

In [5]: 'function2' in globals()
Out[5]: False
```

But,

```
In [7]: 'function1' in locals()
Out[7]: True

In [8]: 'function2' in locals()
Out[8]: True
```

So, if I do:

```
In [11]: globals().update(locals())

In [12]: function2('Juan')
Out[12]: 'hello Juan'
```

Comment: the drawback after defining each function that you intend to use internally you have to update the globals.